# Does magmi can able to download remote images?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magmi

**In this link:**

```
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor
```

**To set base image values**

```
image
small_image
thumbnail
```

**To set base image labels**

```
image_label (label to use for image)
small_image_label (label to use for small_image)
thumbnail_label (label to use for thumbnail image)
```

**A) Whats the differnece between '**image values***' and '**image labels**'*

**B)  All I have a productsFeed.csv file what image columns should keep in it..?**

**C) Does Magmi can able to download remote Images from URL? sinc ein my csv i have all remote images**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your questions are answered in the documentation link you've provided.  But to break them down.

**A) Whats the differnece between '*image values' and 'image labels'**

Image Values contain the path to the image.  Example: `http://website.com/path/to/image.jpg`

Image Labels are the text descriptions assigned to the images.  Example: `Blue Shirt`

**B) All I have a productsFeed.csv file what image columns should keep in it..?**

Your CSV should contain all the image columns you want to upload to Magento.

**C) Does Magmi can able to download remote Images from URL? sinc ein my csv i have all remote images**

Yes, as stated in the documentation.

> Image Processor accepts URL as valid image location for any type of
>   image (standard or extra) **Image processor will download** the remote
>   images & put them in the appropriate directory for magento usage.

Comment: Hi @Axel, I have small issue in magmi images remote accessing from another website, my csv : https://snag.gy/2oPART.jpg. After execution, the images getting from another server and stored all images into catalog/products/desired folder, but the images size like 0,

Comment: The everything is good but images not displayed even folder also, but the name presented in the catalog/products/desired folder : https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO33S.png  and image view url like https://snag.gy/haNQkx.jpg. how can i solve this issue?

Comment: Make sure that the server you're grabbing the images from is allowing your server to grab the images.  You can try testing a curl command using shell.  Something like `curl i.stack.imgur.com/WO33S.png`

Comment: Also, check your folder and file permissions.  If your folder/file permissions on your server aren't set up to allow Magmi to write files, then Magmi won't be able to save the images.  You may be able to find better clues in your log files as to what's happening.

Comment: okay, let me check.. and one more, is possible can i import images label by using Magmi, like sku : 0123 image_label : mankind

Comment: The example provided in the [Magmi Image Attribute Processor Documentation](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor#media_gallery_.28extra_images.29_column_syntax) is ```/extraimg1.jpg::label for img 1;/extraimg2.jpg::label for img 2```